# Append swatches based on multiple images

Tags: jquery

I got a page of products which some have multiple images. I want to append a swatch (only if multiple images exist) that will toggle the image that the swatch relates to. I was thinking adding a title to each image that will be a class which the swatch will be.

For example a product has 3 images. The 1st image is black, 2nd is blue, 3rd pink. Each swatch will gets its class name from the title name of the image. Also each image will toggle the corresponding image as well.

HTML

```
<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic">

<img src="image" title="black" />
<img src="image" title="blue" /> 
<img src="image" title="pink" /> 

</div>
<h1>Nike Shirt</h1>
</li>

<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic">

<img src="image" title="black" />

</div>
<h1>Nike Shirt</h1>
</li>

<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic">

<img src="image" title="yellow" />
<img src="image" title="green" />
</div>
<h1>Nike Shirt</h1>
</li>
```

SWATCH HTML (which will be append automatically if more than 1 image is detected)

```
<ul class='swatch'>
<li class='black'></li>
<li class='blue'></li>
<li class='pink'></li>
<ul>
```

SCRIPT (not complete)

```
var totalImg = $('.mainpic').find('img').length;

if ( totalImg > 1 ) { 

$('.prod .mainpic').append('<ul class="swatches"></ul>');

}
```

FINAL HTML

```
<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic">

<ul class='swatch'>
<li class='black'></li>
<li class='blue'></li>
<li class='pink'></li>
<ul> 

<img src="image" title="black" />
<img src="image" title="blue" /> 
<img src="image" title="pink" /> 

</div>
<h1>Nike Shirt</h1>
</li>

<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic"> 

<img src="image" title="black" />

</div>
<h1>Nike Pants</h1>
</li>

<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic"> 

<ul class='swatch'>
<li class='yellow'></li>
<li class='green'></li>
<ul> 

<img src="image" title="yellow" />
<img src="image" title="green" />
</div>
<h1>Nike Hat</h1>
</li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces exactly the HTML specified.:

```
$('li.prod div.mainpic').each ( function () {
    var jThis           = $(this);
    var mainImages      = jThis.find ('img');

    if ( mainImages.length > 1 ) {
        jThis.prepend ('<ul class="swatches"></ul>');
        var targList    =  jThis.find ('ul.swatches');

        mainImages.each ( function () {
            newClass    =  $(this).attr ('title');
            targList.append ("<li class='" + newClass + "'></li>");
        } );
    }
} );
```

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtZLR/8/) Note that the CSS is just to hopefully make it clearer what's going on.

Results:

```
<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic">

<ul class="swatches">
<li class="black"></li>
<li class="blue"></li>
<li class="pink"></li>
</ul>

<img src="image" title="black" />
<img src="image" title="blue" /> 
<img src="image" title="pink" /> 

</div>
<h1>Nike Shirt</h1>
</li>

<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic">

<img src="image" title="black" />

</div>
<h1>Nike Pants</h1>
</li>

<li class="prod">
<div class="mainpic">

<ul class="swatches">
<li class="yellow"></li>
<li class="green"></li>
</ul>

<img src="image" title="yellow" />
<img src="image" title="green" />
</div>
<h1>Nike Hat</h1>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, Buildingbrick. The updated "Final HTML" is a little confusing as it has missing and mis-matched `</li>` tags.  But if you want the new list to appear before the images, I've updated my answer to show that too.

Comment: I am getting swatches on every product, even the ones with a single img. My page has multiple products. I updated my code to reflect this. Take a look. I tried putting this into the fiddle as well and was getting errors. Try it out and see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) Get all the .mainpic elements
 2) filter the  elements that have  more than 1 image.
 3) for each .mainpic element of step#2 append a holding UL element
 4) iterate through each img element within each .mainpic element of step#2
 5) wrap it with li and append to the ul element created earlier

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $(function() {
                var tgtLis = $(".mainpic").filter(function(){ //Get all the mainpic elements
                    return $(this).children("img").length > 1; //return only if they have  more than 1 image.
                }).each(function(a, b){
                    var $this = $(b);
                    var ul = $this.append("<ul>");  //append a holding UL element for each mainpic
                    $("img", $this).each(function(a, b){ //iterate through each img element
                        ul.append($("<li/>").append(b)); //wrap it with li and append to the ul element created earlier
                    });
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

Working example@: http://jsfiddle.net/Rgz4R/

Comment: FYI - I have other elements in the .mainpic wrapper but I removed for simplification. But the img elements are the only images.

Comment: It worked almost. The <ul> tag appeared on ones with multiple images only. And it wrapped each img in a li tag. but the <ul> did not wrap the li's.

Comment: It does wrap them. Check this jsfiddle post http://jsfiddle.net/Rgz4R/1/ and observe the value alerted. It goes from 1 to 3.

Comment: @Buildingbrick: Did you want the images wrapped in the new `li` tags?!?!  Your question does not state that, nor does the inserted code sample show that!

Comment: I edit the above to reflect the final HTML once the swatch code is appended.